# Some R packages do not update with update.packages()

Tags: r

Selecting `Packages->Update packages...` gave:

```
> update.packages(ask='graphics',checkBuilt=TRUE)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: package 'foreign' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'lattice' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'Matrix' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'mgcv' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'nlme' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'rpart' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' will not be updated
```

I ran the R shortcut in the startup menu "as Administrator" and got the same results.

R version is 3.0.2.

Comment: Maybe you installed these as Administrator and am now running as you?

Comment: As is always encouraged, using a personal library solves exactly these types of minor issues

Comment: @imsoconfused Take note that the packages mentioned are typically in the base install.  So just having a personal library doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: @Dason thanks! i'll keep that in mind - somebody else helped me with this same issue on an external package and using a personal library / Run as Admin fixed it and I hastily applied that same suggestion forward! haha

Comment: @imsoconfused: and anyway I have the personal library active. `libPaths()` gives as expected: `[1] "C:/Users/antonio/R/win-library/3.0"  "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library"`

Comment: could there be something using the packages?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### A general restatement of the question

1. In Windows 7/8 the package `nicePack`, included in the base install, is outdated.
2. You update it with `update.packages()` or via the equivalent GUI menu.
3. You get:
   `Warning: package 'nicePack' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.*.*/library" will not be updated`

### Potential causes

R is not very *kind* with Windows so it just says "will not be updated" and not something like "permission denied to C:/Program Files/R/...". Anyway you realise that R cannot write to `C:/Program Files` and so restart it as Administrator and upgrade, but the problem persists!

If you check the personal package directory, where R is able to write, you see that the updated version of `nicePack` is there. In Windows the directory is normally `~\R\win-library\x.y` or find it with `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")`.

Probably the first time R, unable to write to R default directory, used the personal directory, so that there are two versions of `nicePack`. The second time, despite the admin privileges, R finds the updated package version in the personal directory and it does not update the default directory.

May be that R says "warning" and not "error", because the package *is* installed in the personal directory, but an outdated version remains in the default library.

### Solution

Delete `nicePack` package directory in the personal library directory, restart as administrator and update again.

### Opinions

I don't know if there is an actual bug in this behaviour, anyway more informative messages would for sure  help the Windows user.

Perhaps the default library should be avoided in Windows, in favour of the personal. Many  Windows applications use `C:\ProgramData` or `~\AppData\Local`, writeable without special privileges.

Comment: I'd say there is a bug. The first upgrade of `nicePack` (at a point in time when it's stored only in `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library`) works fine: `'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"' is not writable. Would you like to use a personal library instead?`. However, subsequent updates are ignored.

Comment: What should one do in this situation when on an institutional machine where you do not have administrator privileges?

Answer (score 8):

On R 4.0.4
(Gallium OS 3.1)

Permissions?   old.packages() ?

In my case, I noticed 3 packages that would not update had permissions set differently from others in   `/usr/local/lib/R/library`.

I fixed the permissions, but this did not solve the problem.

Then I ran `old.packages()`  and noted the SAME 3 packages were considered `old`.

I admit I did not quite understand the help in ?update.packages(), but tried the following.

`update.packages(oldPkgs = old.packages())`

This fixed the problem and the 3 packages updated.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me on R 3.6.3 on ubuntu 20.04.3. I didn't need to change permissions before I ran update.packages(old...), either.

Comment: This question was about file permission on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

I am on Ubuntu and i have the same problem from RStudio. I have tried to solve by `sudo R` and `update.packages()`. But it did not help.
However `sudo rstudio` + `update.packages()` have solved the problem.

Comment: Worked in my Arch machine as well, except the executable in my case is called `rstudio-bin` because I have the more upstream "rstutio-desktop-bin" package installed instead of "rstudio-desktop".

Answer (score 2):

In my case worked the following command sequence in the Terminal of Ubuntu:

```
sudo i-
R
update.packages(ask=FALSE)
q(save="no")
logout
```

That is to say: loging as root -> starting R -> updating packages from root -> out of R -> out of root.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we had the following errors:

```
    > install.packages("dplyr")Installing package into ‘C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)also installing the dependency ‘vctrs’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/vctrs_0.6.5.zip'Content type 'application/zip' length 1335663 bytes (1.3 MB)downloaded 1.3 MB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/dplyr_1.1.4.zip'Content type 'application/zip' length 1560779 bytes (1.5 MB)downloaded 1.5 MB
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘vctrs’
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\00LOCK\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘dplyr’

The downloaded binary packages are in
  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKwqJkg\downloaded_packages
```

The resolution was to close PowerBI, as the .dll's were in use by that app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows, but using R Studio Server through SSH tunneling (AWS / Ubunutu Linux). I think that sometimes R Studio adds a layer of difficulties instead of getting things easier, this happens with package dependencies across multiple UNIX users

So, adding this possible scenario that may affect people looking for aforementioned question >>>

You can have a package version on your user 
and other version on

You need to `su root` and install.update() by `SUDO R` (same of R.exe on Windows) with a root user.

Then, when you acess RStudio Server, you'll see *System Library packages updated*

In summary, even if you use only one high-privilege unix user on a server, there will be two different locations for libraries:

ubuntu(user):`/usr/local/lib/R/`

system wide: `/usr/lib/R/library`

Comment: This was the solution for me (see next answer)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, under Ubuntu and after switching to R 4.x, it was because the package (Matrix) was installed with apt.

```
 sudo apt remove r-cran-matrix
```

allowed to handle it normally in R.