# using R and RStudio on linux (ubuntu 23.04)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, chmod

I'm looking to start working with R and RStudio on my ubuntu installation.

I am having problems with updating/installing my packages, sudh as DESeq2. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587440/some-r-packages-do-not-update-with-update-packages) post it is because r-base installs packages into protected os files.

I have followed this posts recommendation but I have not had success. Others recommend chmodding the relative paths...

I am really surprised that the r-base install has this issue. I can't seem to find an updated installation method that avoids the issue. I wanted to ask if anyone had any further advice for overcoming this?

I am also using conda environments, but I have installed R and RStudio into the base environment to avoid problems, I don't think it supports being run through a conda environment.

I've been using ubuntu for a year and I don't want to have a janky R installation to cause headache.

would appreciate all insight.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you encounter the same error messages as in the post you linked? If not could you provide the exact error messages?

Comment: Hi, yes the exact same; have wiped the R installation completely using the steps described in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118558/complete-remove-and-reinstall-r-including-all-packages

Comment: Could you provide the output of `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")` (from the R console)?

Comment: /root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2

Comment: Is it actually an issue for you? As you have recognized, some packages are installed system-wide and cannot be update using R's internal mechanisms (`update.packages()`) but they will get update (a little later) with the system packages (apt upgrade).

Comment: Ok so that's the issue. The path you provided is not writable for you as normal user. You could add 'R_LIBS_USER="~/.R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/"' to the ~/.Renviron in your home directory. Then restart R and try to update the packages.

Comment: Huh. I dug through my logs for a second and actually found that my problem lay elsewhere. Lesson learned to be more meticulous before posting. I thought it was interfering with the installation of DESeq2; but it was actually a missing xml2.config file. Glad to have it fixed. Thank you for your help on following up on this though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you use the Ubuntu binary mirrored at CRAN which follows the Debian binary, then `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` is the defailt local installation. It is recommended to add yourself to group `adm` as the directory is group-witeable.  Of course you can override with `~/R/...`  Some folks, myself included, prefer `/usr/local`.  Mix and match of distro and local is no issue per se -- but we can do a lot better now,  See my answer for [r2u](eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) as different binary approach covering all of CRAN.

Comment: See the solution here for package dependencies on Ubuntu linux 23.10 https://r-ds.github.io/Installing-R-and-Rstudio-on-Ubuntu-23.10/

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Ubuntu 23.04 (which I am running on laptop and server) with [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) offering you 20,000 binary (!!) packages with full dependency resolution. It also has about 250 BioConductor packages inferred by these packages.

You can also try it in Docker. I just did via

```
docker run --rm -ti rocker/r2u         # launches r2u for 22.04
```

followed by (now inside the container)

```
Rscript -e 'system.time(install.packages("DESeq2"))'
```

and it installed 52 (binary) packages in in 15.8 seconds.  Now we have `DESeq2`, and it is under the control of `apt` and will get updates as `apt` gets them.  See the r2u site for more.

Comment: This looks incredible man! Actually just going through setting up packages and its an awful pain installing dependencies manually! Will be sure to get it checked out! Thank you!